# Specifying advanced webpart properties on a view in a custom module?

Tags: web-part, feature

I'm deploying a web part page from a feature. In the module/file node, I defines a view to a specific list in the site :

```
<Module Name="SitePages"
      Url="SitePages"
      SetupPath="1033\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS" >

<File Name="parametres.aspx"
      Path="spstd4.aspx"
      Url="parametres.aspx"
      Type="GhostableInLibrary"> 
  <View WebPartOrder="3"
        WebPartZoneID="Body"
        DisplayName="Entités"
        List="Lists/Entities"  />
</File>
</Module>
```

This is working as expected, but I'd like to configure some advanced properties; For example, I want to define the audience that applies to the webpart. With a custom WebPart, I would have done :

```
  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Body"
                   WebPartOrder="2">
    <![CDATA[<webParts>

  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
<metaData>
  <type name="MyProject.MyWebPart, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
  <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
</metaData>
<data>
  <properties>
    <property name="Title" type="string">WP Title</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string">WP Description</property>
    <property name="AuthorizationFilter" type="string">;;;;Name_Of_My_SharePoint_Group</property>
  </properties>
</data>
</webPart>
</webParts>
]]>
  </AllUsersWebPart>
```

But using `<view>`, I don't have the properties node available.

What are my options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<View WebPartOrder="3"  WebPartZoneID="Body"  DisplayName="Entités"  List="Lists/Entities">
                <![CDATA[
                <webParts>
                    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                        <metaData>
                            <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                            <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                        </metaData>
                        <data>
                            <properties>
                             <property name="Title" type="string">WP Title</property>
                             <property name="Description" type="string">WP  Description</property>
                             <property name="AuthorizationFilter" type="string">;;;;Name_Of_My_SharePoint_Group</property>
                           </properties>
                        </data>
                    </webPart>
                </webParts>
                ]]>
            </View>
```

Comment: Amazing undocumented behavior. I owe you a beer (_)3

Comment: This is not Working.....