# Provision a ListView to a already existing list

Tags: list-view, caml

How do you with CAML provision a View to a already existing list? I know how to add views through list definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a view to a list using the declarative model as you would in a list definition.  The best way to do this would be in a Feature Receiver, using .NET code.

Comment: Sounds good, could you dive into some more details please? If I understood you correct I should write some CAML as in a list definition. But how do I apply It to a list through code? Isn't there a way to apply it declarative?

Comment: No CAML.  You'll need to write code. Get a new SPView, add the columns using myView.Add("Title"), for example.

Comment: OK, never mind, I may stand corrected.  According to this blog, you might be able to add the CAML to the SPView's Query property.http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/31762

Comment: Thank you, the blogs information looks promising. Will dive into it when I got some time over for it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like here :
[Specifying advanced webpart properties on a view in a custom module?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38063/specifying-advanced-webpart-properties-on-a-view-in-a-custom-module/38096#38096)

Comment: Im sorry, I think the correct term to use in my question is View, and not ListView, which I used. The Code you refer to instancitetes a XsltListViewWebPart. Which is something different from what I'm trying to achieve.